# Editing and updaing cfgrid values dynamically

Tags: coldfusion, dynamic-data, coldfusion-8, cfgrid

I need to edit the values of one (or more) column in the cfgrid by double-clicking the value and on pressing enter the cfgrid should update the db with the new value.

I have seen this capability in the flex datagrid . A similar capability is expected.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am newbie to CF so i finally found out how you do that: you need to add the attribute selectMode=edit and moreover you need to add the  onchange attribute.
eg:
onchange = "cfc:getCalculatorData.editCategory({cfgridaction},{cfgridrow},{cfgridchanged})">

Further you write your update query in the cfc editLocation

Example for the cfc function is :

```
    <cfif isStruct(gridrow) and isStruct(gridchanged)>
        <cfif gridaction eq "U">
            <cfset colname=structkeylist(gridchanged)>
            <cfset value=structfind(gridchanged,#colname#)>
            <cfquery name="team" datasource="batcalc"> 
                UPDATE tbl_category SET <cfoutput>#colname#</cfoutput> = 
                    '<cfoutput>#value#</cfoutput>'
                WHERE category_id = <cfoutput>#gridrow.category_id#</cfoutput>
            </cfquery>
        <cfelse>
            <cfquery name="delCat" datasource="batcalc"> 
                DELETE FROM tbl_category 
                WHERE category_id = <cfoutput>#gridrow.category_id#
                    </cfoutput>
            </cfquery> 
        </cfif>
    </cfif>
</cffunction>
```